# Append QueryString in Web Handler (ashx) in form action i.e. form action="FileTransferHandler.ashx

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, handler

I am trying to add a query string to a Web Handler while creating a form action.

`firstName` will come from a drop down.

Can this be done with jQuery?

```
<div>Want something like:</div>

<form action="FileTransferHandler.ashx?firstName="+Tommy+"; method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>

<div>if Possible via jQuery:</div>      

<form action="FileTransferHandler.ashx?firstName=$("#ddlFirstName option:selected").text(); method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
```

Comment: Why? Why will you add something to the query string in a POST From action? You either your get: QueryString or POST: body of the message. It makes no sense what you are doing

Comment: He wants to constructs the querystring for webhandler, which is part of asp.net pipeline

Comment: Form has a POST action not a GET action

Comment: Dude, this not about post or get. The webhandler only know the URL nothing else as in asp.net. That is the reason he wants to send some querystring.

Comment: Hi, I added line of code in js.. $("#search-form").attr("action", "/FileTransferHandler.ashx?tmid=Tommy"); and working perfectly. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Handle the form submit event in Jquery and construct the query you want to add. The form will be posted through JQuery ajax and upon receiving a response from server handle the results.

```
var url = "<actual url"+ <<constructed query string>>;
var jqxhr = $.get( "example.php", function() {
    alert( "success" );
})
.done(function() {
   //handle success response here
})
.fail(function() {
   //handle failure response here
})
.always(function() {
   //either success or fail perform this action
});
```

Comment: Why this was down voted? It will be great if someone leave the reason behind it.